# How to make a project of Krusader

Tags: 12.04, kde, qt, source, krusader

An example for my general question https://askubuntu.com/questions/485242/an-introduction-to-translating-and-debugging-source-code : I had installed the 'Qt 4 Designer' and I have downloaded the krusader-2.4.0-beta3.tar.bz2 file. Among the packed files I see the `CMakeLists.txt` that contains

```
project(krusader)
INCLUDE(CPack)
set(VERSION "2.4.0-beta3" )
set(RELEASE_NAME "Single Step")
find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)
include(KDE4Defaults)
include_directories( ${KDE4_INCLUDES} ${KDE4_INCLUDE_DIR} ${QT_INCLUDES}  )
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF)
add_definitions(${QT_DEFINITIONS} ${KDE4_DEFINITIONS})
add_definitions( "-DKRARC_ENABLED" )
find_package(ACL)
if(ACL_FOUND)
    add_definitions(-DHAVE_POSIX_ACL)
endif(ACL_FOUND)
\#include(ConfigureChecks.cmake)
add_subdirectory(krusader)
add_subdirectory(pics)
add_subdirectory(doc-extras)
add_subdirectory(krArc)
add_subdirectory(iso)
add_subdirectory(doc)
\#add_subdirectory(krfiledialog) - not used
\#add_subdirectory(virt) - not used
\#add_subdirectory(tar) - not used
message(STATUS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}: skipped subdir $(TARDIR)")
include(MacroOptionalAddSubdirectory)
macro_optional_add_subdirectory( po )
```

I guess that I am to find or choose my directories and define them using

```
KDE4_INCLUDES=the directory
```

etc. I need an introduction about rules for it; maybe the directories are among the following

```
/home/me_user/.kde/share/kde4/
/home/me_user/Ot/5.l.0/android_x86/src/android/java/src/org/kde/
/home/me_user/Ot/5.1.0/android_armv7/src/android/java/src/org/kde/
/home/me_user/G/Ot/krusader-2.4.0-beta3/pics/kde3/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/fpicker/source/unx/kde_unx/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/fpicker/source/unx/kde4/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/fpicker/source/unx/kde/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/scp2/source/kde/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/extras/unx/source/kde/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/shell/source/backends/kde4be/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/shell/source/backends/kdebe/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/vcl/unx/kde4/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/vcl/unx/kde/
/home/me_user/G/libreoffice-3.5.7.2/core/vcl/inc/unx/kde/
/tmp/kde-me_userMYlhh5/
/var/tmp/kdecache-root/
/var/tmp/kdecache-me_user/
/var/tmp/kdecache-she_user/
/var/tmp/kdecache-me_user/kio_help/usr/share/doc/kde/
/usr/share/kde4/
/usr/share/applications/kde4/
/usr/share/emoticons/kde4/
/usr/share/pyshared/softwareproperties/kde/
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_SCRIPTS/kdelibs4/
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_SCRIPTS/kdelibs4/
/usr/share/doc/kde-l10n-cs/
/usr/share/doc/kdepim-runtime/
/usr/share/doc/kde-l10n-sk/
/usr/share/doc/kdepimlibs-kio-plugins/
/usr/share/doc/kde-l10n-de/
/usr/share/doc/kdelibs5-plugins/
/usr/share/doc/kde-l10n-engb/
/usr/share/doc/kde-runtime/
/usr/share/doc/kde/
/usr/share/doc/kde-runtime-data/
/usr/share/doc/kdelibs-bin/
/usr/share/doc/kdelibs5-data/
/usr/share/doc/kde-l10n-ru/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/en/kdesu/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/en/kdebugdialog/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/en/kcontrol/kded/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/ru/kdesu/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/ru/kdebugdialog/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/de/kdesu/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/de/kdepasswd/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/de/kdebugdialog/
/usr/share/doc/kde/HTML/de/kcontrol/kded/
/usr/share/kde4/apps/kdeui/
/usr/share/kde4/apps/kdewidgets/
/usr/share/kde4/apps/kde/
/usr/share/kde4/services/kded/
/usr/share/gettext/projects/KDE/
/usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Kde/
/usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Element/Kde/
/usr/share/ontology/kde/
/usr/lib/kde4/
/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/kdesu~distrib/
/usr/lib/kde4/platformimports/touch/org/kde/
/usr/lib/kde4/imports/org/kde/
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/kde/
```

Or should I install yet another package from KDE?

I have tried opening

```
krusaderversion.h.cmake
```

(the only `*.cmake` file from the download) in the 'Qt Creator' and building it, but it demands many parameters. I'd like to know how to find the parameters, as far as possible directly from the downloaded files. This is what I meant by a "general introduction 'how to make such projects'", maybe for KDE projects particularly; is something like it available?

Comment: If your question is not specific to ubuntu, use http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: I do not tend to super general Linux solutions; I want to use my Ubuntu 12.04 routinely and adjust its tools to  what I need; now, to adjust them to be able to work with them similarly as I am used from Windows XP, MS office 2003, Total Commander and Visual Studio 6.0.

Comment: Evidently my question 485386 shows to be yet too general. Particularly: Please, what should I install into the Ubuntu 12.04 to satisfy the line 'find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)' of the CMakeLists.txt? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The matter of the command `find_package(KDE4 REQUIRED)` is solved in my answer to [How to get KDE4 for building a project in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486008/how-to-get-kde4-for-building-a-project-in-ubuntu-12-04/486475#486475).

Similarly, installing `zlib1g-dev` enabled me to open the `CMakeLists.txt` as a 'Qt 4 Designer' project via `cmake` (without parameters) and to build it; Qt accepted dependencies of the sources.

I have attained my goal - now I can watch how Krusader works by using the debugger. (Similar steps for the stable Krusader version led to error messages during translation, evidently I have made a mistake, maybe at a version of some dependency; I am satisfied by watching the Krusader version I use.)